How to see all dependencies (include plugins and etc) in Gradle for my project?
I need to collect all dependencies for my project (Java/Kotlin, using Gradle): include plugins and all deps.
Why? Because i need to build my projects with another Nexus (isolated Nexus in isolated environment).
I want to do it with two steps:

Collect all deps and move it to isolated Nexus
Build projects with isolated Nexus which contains all deps of my
project (through previous step)

Gradle version 7.2+
Already tried gradle tasks dependencies and buildEnvironment, but it's not appeared to show all deps (for example transitive deps).
Now i can collect all deps by searching .gradle/caches and parse dirs with deps. But i think Gradle can do it without my dirty hack solution.

dependencies does show transitive dependencies (docs). As for your final goal, it may be that I don't understand it fully, but your build scripts themselves are precisely what you need to build your project in another environment, I would have thought

I need to build project in isolated environment, for that purpose i need to sync isolated nexus. Isolated Nexus doesn't have internet access, and what i think: collect all deps, plugins for project and download it manually.
But dependencies doesn't contain information about plugins and etc - and i can't build project.

You are on a hard road if your project is of any complexity if you want to reproduce a build in the absence of internet access. Can't you just compile your program and deploy it to wherever it needs to be in that form? If not why is it necessary to build it in situ?

Because it's regulator requirement..
Thats why i want  upload all deps and plugins in isolated Nexus
